# Why do the evil Decepticons get the best weapons?

Tags: transformers

I've seen all parts of *Transformers*. But every time the *Decepticons* get the best weapons and more advanced technologies than the *Autobots*.

E.g. in the first part *Megatron* and *Starscream* can transform into airplanes. This repeats in all following parts.

Why is this difference between them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It goes back to the ideological differences between the Autobots and the Decepticons. Both sides are Transformers who can modify their bodies. The Autobots believe in peaceful coexistence with the rest of the universe, so their alt modes (the alternate shape they transform into) mirror that: cars and trucks so that they can exist among people without being noticed. The Decepticons on the other hand believe that they are destined to conquer the universe, so their alt modes are weapons of war: jet fighters and tanks ... etc.

Comment: Seems nice and in-universe logical answer.

Answer (score 5):

I don't disagree with System Down's answer; it's a good in-universe response.  But there is also a real-world answer:  If the Decepticons didn't have some kind of advantage, there wouldn't be a story.

Before any Transformers movie is made (or, indeed, virtually any Hollywood action movie), there are some guidelines the story is expected to follow:  the heroes must be placed in jeopardy, they must appear to be on the verge of defeat, but they must somehow emerge victorious.  You can see this structure clearly in sports movies: they are nearly always
about underdogs who somehow achieve an unexpected victory.

So how are you going to set up the next Transformers movie?  The Decepticons need to
seem more powerful and dangerous than the Autobots, so they had better start off with
better weaponry.  (But it will turn out all right in the end.)